# Jquery DatePicker change highlighted color onSelect of a particular date

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have this code of Jquery datepicker that I am working on. 
What I want to do is change the color of the current highlighted date to grey when I click on anyother date, and the color of the clicked date to green.

The tricky part is that only the ones which are grey can turn green and viceversa but no other dates can turn into green on click.

I dont understand what I am doing wrong. Or is it that my code is completely wrong.
If anyone can help.

here's the code

```
$(function() {
     var togo=['10/25/2013']
     var datesArray=['10/27/2013','10/28/2013']
     var datesArray1=['10/25/2013','10/26/2013']
     var datesArray2=['10/24/2013']


        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,

            selectMultiple:true,
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var theday = (date.getMonth()+1) +'/'+ 
                            date.getDate()+ '/' + 
                            date.getFullYear();
                    return [true,$.inArray(theday, datesArray2) >=0?"specialDate":($.inArray(theday, datesArray)>=0?"specialDate2":($.inArray(theday, datesArray1)>=0?"specialDate1":''))];
                },

            onSelect: function(date){

             console.log("clicked"+date);  
            return [true,$.inArray(date, togo) >=0?"specialDate":($.inArray(date, datesArray1)>=0?"specialDate1":'')] ;  

            }

        });
        //$.inArray(theday, datesArray) >=0?"specialDate":'specialDate1'
    });
```

For a clearer picture of what I am doing and what I want heres a JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/Kyt2w/3/

thanks.

Comment: Which grey, the light or dark?

Comment: the dark one, not the light thats just the jquery ui theme

Comment: when I click on the dark grey dates they should turn to green,that is in the example 25 or 26th and 24th should again turn to dark grey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onSelect` does not behave like `beforeShowDay`.  You cannot return an array with `[true/false, class, popup]`.  Instead, you will have to apply the class manually in the function.

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but I would rearrange your code a bit.  I made a array with the gray dates, then a variable with the green date.  I never change the array, but update the green date on click, and then call a `refresh` on the `datepicker`:

```
$(function () {
    var togo = [ '10/25/2013' ];
    var redDates = [ '10/27/2013', '10/28/2013' ];
    var grayDates = [ '10/24/2013', '10/25/2013', '10/26/2013' ];
    var greenDate = '10/24/2013';


    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,

        selectMultiple: true,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var theday = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
            return [true, greenDate == theday ? "specialDate" : ($.inArray(theday, redDates) >= 0 ? "specialDate2" : ($.inArray(theday, grayDates) >= 0 ? "specialDate1" : ""))];
        },

        onSelect: function (dateStr) {
            var date = new Date(dateStr);
            var theday = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();

            if ($.inArray(theday, grayDates) >= 0) {
                greenDate = theday;
            }
            $('#datepicker').datepicker("refresh");
        }

    });
});
```

I wasn't sure what `togo` was for, but this should get you started.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xU47h/3/

Comment: yes u are correct on that, I tried doing an .addClass(".ui-datepicker-current-day") to a green color but it does not override..

Comment: Hello Jeff, there is a problem with the fiddle you  made. When you change the data to a supposing 10/01/2013 to 10/04/2013 as gray and try to make it green it does not work.   its the issue with the date format for javascript. Trying to work on it.

Comment: this is the fiddle where you will see the problem  http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/xU47h/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/xU47h/2/ Use this fiddle it works with all the cases.

Comment: @user2415379 There is a simpler solution than that.  Instead of doing the date parsing yourself, let javascript do it for you: `date = new Date(date)`, and then use `theday` calculation like in `beforeShowDay`.  Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xU47h/3/

Comment: ohh yes I was trying the same thing before.. was getting an error so tried doing a quick fix which would do the work.. but yes  yours edit is what it should be. 


thumbs up.. thanks.